# Compressing PDF with ghostscript in .bat file - missing text

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ghostscript

I am trying to compress PDF file and turn it grayscale with .bat script and i have big problem.

When i do the compression, the text in PDF turns red, when i added grayscale lines, after script finished its job, text is white/Gone.

Can someone help me fix it so the text can be still black? My script part:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -sOutputICCProfile=sgray.icc -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dCompressFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile="%TEMP%\%%~nxf" "%%~f"
```

Here is the image before and after compression :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using. You have not supplied the PDF file so that it can be investigated (pictures may show the problem, they are not helpful for diagnosing or fixing it).

You should not set `-dProcessColorModel`, especially not when you have set `-sColorConversionStrategy`.

You absolutely should not be setting `-sOutputICCProfile`.

There's really no point in setting `PDFCompatibilityLevel` higher than the pdfwrite device already sets it, unless you are adding content via pdfmark operators which requires a higher level (and you aren't doing that).

There's also no point in setting `CompressFonts=true` or `EmbedAllFonts=true`, as these are the default values.

When you are trying to diagnose a problem, don't set `-dQUIET`, you want Ghostscript to tell you about anything it thinks might be a problem.

On Windows (which I assume this is because you are talking about a .bat file) the Ghostscript executable is called gswin32, gswin32c, gswin64 or gswin64c, not gs. So I'm somewhat puzzled as to how you;re getting this to work at all.

You have set `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` **after** setting `-sColorConversionStrategy`, if you look at the table of settings in the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE) you will see that the /ebook setting sets the colour conversion strtaegy to RGB, since that comes later on the command line than **your** `ColorConversionStrategy`, that's the one that takes precedence. The confusion between `ProcessColorModel` (DeviceGray, from your command line) and `ColorConversionStrategy` (RGB from the PDFSETTINGS value) is very possibly what is causing your problem.

When faced with this kind of problem I'd suggest you simplify the command line until you figure out what exactly is causing it. I would also suggest that you don't use PDFSETTINGS at all, as that changes **many** configuration controls all at once. Figure out which ones you want to use and turn them on individually.

As a final point, Ghostscript's pdfwrite device doesn't 'compress' PDF files, it produces PDF files from its input. If you choose to take action such as downsampling images or altering the colour space then it's possible that a new PDF file will be smaller than an input PDF file. It's not compressed though, it's smaller because you have discarded information.

Comment: Thank you, thats a lot of info. I use ghostscript 9.27 by cygwin, that why gs works. I will try to check all options now but you helped already a lot.